# Create array from single character at a certain position of a different array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

```
myArray = ["1324","11455","2234","55345", "1234", "54321"]
```

How do I break that into 5 arrays, each containing one of the 5 characters from that array?

Wanted result is

```
firstCharacterArray => ["1","1","2","5","1","5"]
...
fifthCharacterArray => ["","5","","5","","1"]
```

Comment: What have you tried? It's important to show us what you've attempted, so we can help you fix it, instead of you asking for us to write code for you. Also, in Ruby we use snake_case for variable names, not camelCase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
first_character_array = myArray.map{ |e| e[0] }.map{ |e| e.nil? ? "" : e }
=> ["1", "1", "2", "5", "1", "5"] 
...
fifth_character_array = myArray.map{ |e| e[4] }.map{ |e| e.nil? ? "" : e }
=> ["", "5", "", "5", "", "1"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
def extract_n_character(arr, n)
  arr.map { |c| c[n] || '' }
end

extract_n_character(myArray, 0)
# => ["1", "1", "2", "5", "1", "5"]

extract_n_character(myArray, 4)
# => ["", "5", "", "5", "", "1"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try using this as a starting point:

```
my_array = ["1324", "11455", "2234", "55345", "1234", "54321"]
max_size = my_array.max_by{ |s| s.size }.size # => 5
arrays = my_array.map{ |s| s.split('') }.map{ |a| 
  (a.size < max_size) ? 
  a += ([''] * (max_size - a.size)) : 
  a 
}
```

Here's what `arrays` looks like:

```
arrays 
# => [["1", "3", "2", "4", ""],
#     ["1", "1", "4", "5", "5"],
#     ["2", "2", "3", "4", ""],
#     ["5", "5", "3", "4", "5"],
#     ["1", "2", "3", "4", ""],
#     ["5", "4", "3", "2", "1"]]
```

And here's how to get the desired arrays:

```
arrays.transpose
# => [["1", "1", "2", "5", "1", "5"],
#     ["3", "1", "2", "5", "2", "4"],
#     ["2", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3"],
#     ["4", "5", "4", "4", "4", "2"],
#     ["", "5", "", "5", "", "1"]]
```

Or:

```
arrays.shift.zip(*arrays)
# => [["1", "1", "2", "5", "1", "5"],
#     ["3", "1", "2", "5", "2", "4"],
#     ["2", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3"],
#     ["4", "5", "4", "4", "4", "2"],
#     ["", "5", "", "5", "", "1"]]
```

This smells like homework or a tutorial assignment. If it is homework, consider that teachers can easily search and find the answers given here.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd get the [`length`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-length) of the longest string in the array using [`Enumerable#max_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by).

Then, I would pad the shorter strings with [`String#ljust`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-ljust) (so they all have the same length) and use [`String#chars`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-chars) to get an array of characters for each string.

Last, I would [`transpose`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-transpose) the rows and columns of this two-dimensional array.

```
array = ["1324","11455","2234","55345", "1234", "54321"]

max = array.max_by(&:length).length
array.map { |s| s.ljust(max).chars }.transpose
#=> [["1", "1", "2", "5", "1", "5"],
#    ["3", "1", "2", "5", "2", "4"],
#    ["2", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3"],
#    ["4", "5", "4", "4", "4", "2"],
#    [" ", "5", " ", "5", " ", "1"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
firstCharacterArray = []
firstCharacterArray = myArray.each{|firstCharacterArray.push(a[0])}
```